# Errors when launching a build on TeamCity

Tags: python, server, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I wanted to launch my bot on Plato, created a project, connected the git repository, launched it and constantly issues the same error, what is it? help.

```
Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
17:44:35 The build is removed from the queue to be prepared for the start
17:44:35 Starting the build on the agent "Default Agent"
17:44:39 Updating tools for build
17:44:39 Clearing temporary directory: /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
17:44:39 Publishing internal artifacts
17:44:40 Using vcs information from agent file: dca053205897d7da.xml
17:44:40 Checkout directory: /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/dca053205897d7da
17:44:40 Updating sources: auto checkout (on agent)
17:44:41 Step 1/1: Python
17:44:41   Starting: sh /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/script_1706550281468_5266d279-6922-4f40-9691-f1fd59e91080}18296552743297839610.sh
17:44:41   in directory: /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/dca053205897d7da
17:44:41   Create Venv environment
17:44:41     /usr/bin/python3 -m venv .venv
17:44:41     The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
17:44:41     available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
17:44:41     package using the following command.
17:44:41     
17:44:41         apt install python3.10-venv
17:44:41     
17:44:41     You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
17:44:41     package, recreate your virtual environment.
17:44:41     
17:44:41     Failing command: ['/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/dca053205897d7da/.venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
17:44:41     
17:44:41     Process failed with code 1
17:44:41   Process exited with code 1
17:44:41   Python error: Failed with exit code 1
17:44:41   Step Python failed
17:44:49 Publishing artifacts
17:44:50 Publishing internal artifacts
17:44:50 Publishing internal artifacts
17:44:50 Build finished
```

I searched the Internet and found nothing